# Create Observable from multiple FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an `Observable<FormGroup>` that has a couple of boolean `FormControl`

```
readonly someForm$ = model$.pipe(map((model: Model) => {
  return new FormGroup({
    foo: new FormControl(model.getFoo()),
    bar: new FormControl(model.getBar()),
  });
}));
```

I would like to create an observable that emits if any of the `FormControl` values are `true`. I tried the following

```
readonly result$ = someForm$.pipe(switchMap(
  form => form.valueChanges.pipe(
    map(changes => changes.foo || changes.bar),
    startWith(() => form.value['foo'] || form.value['bar'])
  )
));
```

Though `result$` always resolves to `true` during testing. What is the proper way to create an observable that is essentially `foo || bar`?

Minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bvy7bj

Comment: Could you make a reproducible stackblitz?

Comment: @martin I added a small example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bvy7bj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several issues:

- You have `result$` in your component and `$result` in your template.
- `startWith()` doesn't accept a function, it needs to be a value in your use-case.
- You make two subscriptions to `someForm$` which creates two unrelated `FormGroup` instances. You'll need to use `shareReplay(1)` at the end of `someForm$`.

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-xpqmcs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! The `result$` vs `$result` was just me being sloppy creating that example, but the latter two points work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` operator to filter out falsey values

```
const result$ = someForm$.pipe(
  switchMap((form) =>
    form.valueChanges.pipe(
      filter((changes) => changes.foo || changes.bar),
      map((changes) => changes.foo || changes.bar)
    )
  )
);
```

I have created simulated form and simulated user events

```
import { BehaviorSubject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
const someForm$ = of({ // custom Observable form
  valueChanges: new BehaviorSubject({
    foo: false,
    bar: false,
  }),
  value: {
    foo: false,
    bar: false,
  },
});

const result$ = someForm$.pipe(
  switchMap((form) =>
    form.valueChanges.pipe(
      filter((changes) => changes.foo || changes.bar), // filtering falsey values
      map((changes) => changes.foo || changes.bar) // map to true
    )
  )
);

result$.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data); 
});

someForm$.subscribe((data) => {
  data.valueChanges.next({ foo: false, bar: true }); // custom user event
  data.valueChanges.next({ foo: false, bar: false }); // custom user event
  data.valueChanges.next({ foo: true, bar: false }); // custom user event
});
```

demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tfqjms?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100